# if (specialmarkId != null) {.....} got ignored

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I am using auto generated `JPAController` of Netbeans 8 using Java 1.8.

```
public void create(Physical physical) {
        if (physical.getTalentCollection() == null) {
            physical.setTalentCollection(new ArrayList<Talent>());
        }
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Specialmark specialmarkId = physical.getSpecialmarkId();
            System.out.println(specialmarkId+ "...nullValue");
           if (specialmarkId != null) {
                System.out.println(specialmarkId+ "...ain't right");
                specialmarkId = em.getReference(specialmarkId.getClass(), specialmarkId.getId());
                physical.setSpecialmarkId(specialmarkId);
            }
.....
}
```

During physical object creation, `Specialmark` (part of physical object) is an optional.

It can have a value or be null.

`Specialmark` in the table physical allows you to have null values.

When `Specialmark` is null, the `if (specialmarkId != null) {...}` should skipped. Instead, it got ignored and proceed.

the error message is

```
"... An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
at db.jpa.PhysicalJpaController.create(PhysicalJpaController.java:57)"

 System.out.println(specialmarkId+ "...nullValue");
output "null...nullValue" it shows specialmarkId value is null

System.out.println(specialmarkId+ "...ain't right");
```

Output `"null...ain't right"` shows `if (specialmarkId != null) {...}` has been ignored even `specialmarkId` is null.

Why does `(specialmarkId != null) {...}` not work?

Comment: Do you know how to add a breakpoint and inspect the variable? If not then you should learn how to debug, because you are going to need it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `specialmarkId` is not really null, but `specialmarkId.toString()` is overwriten for it to return the string `"null"`.

Instead of

```
System.out.println(specialmarkId+ "...nullValue");
```

try something like

```
System.out.println((specialmarkId != null?
        specialmarkId.toString() + "(not  null)": "(this IS REALLY NULL)")
        + "...nullValue");
```